# How to disable close button in the dialog

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

```
 jQ('#dvShiftDialog').dialog({
                        title : 'Confirm',
                        modal : true,
                        draggable : false,
                        resizable : false,
                        disabled : false,
                        closeOnEscape : false,
                        width : 400,
                        height : 325,
                        close : function() {
                            jQ('#dvShiftDialog').dialog("destroy");
                            jQ('#dvShiftDialog').remove();
                            jQ('div.ui-dialog').remove();
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: I just want disabe close button in that code

Comment: with that code, you dont have a close button ... you dont have any buttons!

Answer (score 2):

If you are referring to the "X" in the upper right corner (since, by your code, you technically don't have any "buttons") you can use the following:

```
open: function(e, ui) {
    jQ(this).siblings(".ui-dialog-titlebar").children(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide();
}
```

Place it in your function as follows:

```
jQ('#dvShiftDialog').dialog({
    title: 'Confirm',
    modal: true,
    draggable: false,
    resizable: false,
    disabled: false,
    closeOnEscape: false,
    width: 400,
    height: 325,
    close: function() {
        jQ('#dvShiftDialog').dialog("destroy");
        jQ('#dvShiftDialog').remove();
        jQ('div.ui-dialog').remove();
    },
   open: function(e, ui) {
       jQ(this).siblings(".ui-dialog-titlebar").children(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide();
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it like this....

```
$('#dvShiftDialog').dialog({
    title : 'Confirm',
    modal : true,
    width : 400,
    height : 325,
    open: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).parent().find(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide();
    }
});
```

​